# Redirect URI mismatch iOS soundcloud

Tags: ios, oauth, soundcloud

I'm developping an iOS app which use soundcloud API.

I followed this tutorial : https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI

Everything was fine until the login step.. I try to upload a song (just to try something different), but I had the same result... No fields to logged in.

Sometimes the soundcloud popup disappear after 1 second, other times, nothing appends, the UI stay in this state (with the spinner active).

In the console, I've got this error message :

> Ooops, something went wrong: Redirect URI mismatch

On the soundcloud website I put an URI like this one myApp://oauth2, and I wrote the same in the initialize method.

I'm not sure it worked, because when I refresh the editing page, the redirect URI field is blank...

Any idea ?

I'm trying to login to soundcloud with this code :

```
[SCSoundCloud requestAccessWithPreparedAuthorizationURLHandler:^(NSURL *preparedURL){

    SCLoginViewController *loginViewController;
    loginViewController = [SCLoginViewController
                           loginViewControllerWithPreparedURL:preparedURL
                           completionHandler:^(NSError *error){

                               if (SC_CANCELED(error)) {
                                   NSLog(@"Canceled!");
                               } else if (error) {
                                   NSLog(@"Ooops, something went wrong: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                               } else {
                                   NSLog(@"Done!");
                               }
                           }];

    [self presentModalViewController:loginViewController
                            animated:YES];

}];
```

Thanks !

Comment: I've heard of some people having trouble with the Redirect URI field in the app registration page. Can you try registering a new app and see if you have the same problem?

Comment: it worked! I feel so stupid for not tried this! Thanks !

Comment: You're not stupid, it shouldn't have happened in the first place! Glad to hear it's working now though :-)