# Sign in with Devise, Omniauth and SoundCloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, soundcloud

I'm trying to sign in my Rails application using Devise and Omniauth. I've already installed omniauth-soundcloud and omniauth gems. I've created an application in Soundcloud with:

```
name: sitename
url: http://127.0.0.1:3000
redirect_url: http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

I followed the steps similarly to Railscasts #235 and the link for signing in is created but when I click, I get redirected to the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirection+URI+provided+does+not+match+a+pre-registered+value.&state=e917179df8ad4e1e1cbef8f8b3d4497c59cf774853a78f94
```

What's happening? Should I forget about Devise for this?
Thanks!

EDIT

Sorry guys, I forgot to delete 'omniauth' gem in the Gemfile. That was causing troubles, everything running know.

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed Ryan Bate's Railscast - this is the URI (development) - `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/soundcloud/callback`

Answer (score 0):

Could this be your answer? Register a new app with soundcloud?

[Redirect URI mismatch iOS soundcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728139/redirect-uri-mismatch-ios-soundcloud)